# Convert an image strip into gif

Tags: animated-gif, image-conversion

By "image strip" I mean a sequence of images all concatenated into one, single, long image. For example, assuming each frame is of equal size at 128x128 pixels

```
------------------------------
| 1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
------------------------------
```

The image strip above would have dimensions of 640x128.
How can I convert this to a GIF file so that I can have to loop through frames 1 to 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org) to do this.

Use the [*crop*](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) [operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) to crop/separate the images, then [combine them](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/) into an animated GIF with different frame-specific options (delay etc.) as required.

If there are no frame-specific options then I think you might even be able to combine both the steps (i.e. frame cropping and animated GIF creation).

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure what to use in ImageMagick but that will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Imageforge for free, and import the image strip as an animation. Then tell the program how many frames, and it will automatically create the animation.